# How to replace a string using regular expression?

Tags: regex, bash

I am stuck at replacing a set of strings using bash.
The strings looks like set18set18_nopep.fa. I want to replace the string with set18/set18_nopep.fa .The number can go from 1-9999 . So the number of digits is also variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put a slash between the end of the numbers and the word `set`:

```
$ s=set18set18_nopep.fa
$ echo "$s" | sed -r 's|([[:digit:]])set|\1/set|'
set18/set18_nopep.fa
```

To assign the new value to a string called `t`:

```
$ t=$(echo "$s" | sed -r 's|([[:digit:]])set|\1/set|')
$ echo "$t"
set18/set18_nopep.fa
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo set18set18_nopep.fa | sed 's|[0-9]\+|&/|'
```

Output:

```
set18/set18_nopep.fa
```